# Parse serialization of a preorder tree traversal

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, tree

I would like to parse a String (serialization of a preorder tree traversal) to JSON objects (nodes and edges of a tree).

**Question**

How would you extract the edges between the nodes?

**String Representation**

The String contains the nodes and the dependencies between the nodes (edges).

The forward symbol will be a simple '>' and the empty (or reverse one level) symbol will be a simple '<' character.

Example:

```
'1>2>5<6<<3>4>7(<<<<)'
```

**Extract Elements**

In order to extract the elements (nodes, edges), I preprocess the String by using a regexp.

```
var network_info = '1>2>5<6<<3>4>7(<<<<)';
var network_elements = network_info.replace(/(\(<*\))/,'').match(/<|>|[0-9]/g);
```

The result is

```
Array [ "1", ">", "2", ">", "5", "<", "6", "<", "<", "3", ">", "4", ">", "7"]
```

**Extract Nodes**

In order to extract the nodes, I defined the function "getNodes".

```
function getNodes(network_elements) {
    var nodes = [];
    var node_id = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < network_elements.length; i++) {
        if(network_elements[i] != '<' && network_elements[i] != '>') {
            var node = {};
            node.id = node_id++;
            node.label = network_elements[i];
            nodes.push(node);
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

The result is a List of JSON objects containing id and label of the nodes

```
[
{id: 1, label: '1'},
{id: 2, label: '2'},
{id: 3, label: '5'},
{id: 4, label: '6'},
...]
```

**Issue: Edges**

The result of the edges should look like the following (from and to denote the id's of the corresponding nodes.

```
[
{id: 1, from: 1, to: 2},
{id: 2, from: 2, to: 3},
{id: 3, from: 2, to: 4},
{id: 4, from: 1, to: 5},
{id: 5, from: 5, to: 6},
{id: 6, from: 6, to: 7}
]
```

Example Pseudo Code

```
var edges = [];
var edge_id = 1;
var from_node_id = 1;
var to_node_id = 2;

LOOP:

    GET from_node_id

    var edge = {};
    edge.id = edge_id++;
    edge.from = from_node_id;
    edge.to = to_node_id++;
    edges.push(edge);
```

**Tree Result**

The tree for the string '1>2>5<6<<3>4>7(<<<<)' looks like this

[Example Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOjYt.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much -tao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a stack of nodes to track the current path to the root. Push the initial node on the stack. Then when you see `>X`, add a left edge from current top of stack to node `X` and push `X` on the stack.  When you see `<...< Y`, pop one node off the stack for each `<`, then add a new right edge from the top of stack to `Y`.

You seem to have no problem with the JSON details. I'll let those for you to work out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The proposed solution works and solved the issue !